# limitation of Google Cloud PubSub subscriptions per project

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

In [Google PubSub Quotas section](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas), it states that project can have no more than 10,000 subscriptions. Am I understanding this correct that even if i have 100 topics, then I can just have total of 10,000 subscriptions in overall? If this understanding is correct and if Google PubSub is so much scalable, why there is such low limitation?

Comment: Could you describe a use case where you would need to support more than 10000 subscriptions to a topic?

Comment: I am not talking about a topic, instead about the project limitation. The project can have only 10,000 subscriptions as written in the quota section.

Comment: Please replace "topic" with "project" in my question, it was an error. I would like to understand what line of reasoning led you to judge the limit as being low. The subscribers of the topic would be applications, not users, so I view this as a generous limit. At 100 topics, you can still support 100 applications consuming each topic. Though this aspect does not scale, the quota page shows that the throughput *does* scale to "Unlimited" if requested.

Comment: why subscribers cannot be users? Is the pub-sub messaging service won't suggest that the user should be connected to it?

Comment: Users could absolutely be subscribers, but this is not a best practice nor its intended use. Applications should handle delivering messages to intended users. The product page shows the typical use case here https://cloud.google.com/images/pubsub/diagram-pubsub.svg

Comment: From this doc: https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/application-services. "Unlike Amazon SNS, Cloud Pub/Sub is intended for application and system integrations rather than direct communication with end-user interfaces such as mobile phones or web pages. For this type of client-server communication, you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging, Cloud Platform's solution for sending push notifications to multiple mobile devices."

Answer (score 2):

The service *is* scalable in terms of throughput. The throughput quotas do have an initial default, however they can be raised by request.

It's true the service will not scale to support your presumed use case of delivering messages directly to users, which could easily exceed 10,000 subscribers across all topics. Nevertheless, the service is [not designed for this use](http://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/application-services):

> Cloud Pub/Sub is intended for application and system integrations
>   rather than direct communication with end-user interfaces

If you need to support [user subscriptions](http://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/application-services):

> For this type of
>   client-server communication, you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging,
>   Cloud Platform's solution for sending push notifications to multiple
>   mobile devices.

Comment: Here is a use case where I need more than 10,000 subscriptions.  My application allows my users to be notified when their business receives a new review via the google my business (GMB) api.  The GMB api only allows notifications through Google Pub/Sub.  The message that GMB sends does not offer me any information to identify the user in my system. It offers no way to inject metadata.  Many users can belong to 1 account.  Therefore I need a subscription per user so I know which of my users' GMB accounts generated the message.  Same for gmail.  10,000 seems arbitrary and a low limit.